# Image Validation

Tags: php, image, validation

I'm new in PHP and I'm trying to make an image validation with TYPE and SIZE but I've failed. Can anyone please help me ?

Here is my code:

```
if($fileName)
    {
        $filePath="images/admin/".$fileName;
        if(file_exists($filePath))
        {
            $a=gmdate("Yzhis");
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/admin/".$a.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $fileName=$a.$_FILES["image"]["name"];

        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/admin/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        }
    }
```

This code is uploading the files fine, but it's not doing the validation.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, it just upload files. What else would you expect that code to do? :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you checked the PHP and Web Server logs? What do they tell you? Is your PHP.ini configured properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both of this function.

```
filesize ()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

```
getimagesize ()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Get a complete list of GD and Image functions.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Answer (score 1):

Image validation can get as complex as you want, but the simplest way is good old [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) function. Test its output against `false` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["gd"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or a similar library to validate and manipulate images in PHP.